# Awesomium not loading HTTPS web application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, awesomium

This is what I have in my WPF application, I am using the Awesomium web browser control along with MVVM and Caliburn.Micro.

In my ShellViewModel I have the following code in the OnViewReady method

```
        if (!WebCore.IsInitialized)
        {
            WebCore.Initialize(
                new WebConfig()
                {
                    HomeURL = "http://www.ic24.org.uk".ToUri(),
                    LogPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\nstevens\AppData\Local\IC24\Cleo", "logs"),
                    LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose
                });
        }

        webControl = new WebControl
                             {
                                 Source = "https://newcleodev.sehnp.nhs.uk/".ToUri(), // this is a locally hosted web application
                                 WebSession =
                                     WebCore.CreateWebSession(
                                         @"C:\SessionDataPath",
                                         new WebPreferences
                                             {
                                                 WebSecurity = false,
                                                 AllowInsecureContent = true
                                             })
                             };
        webControl.WebSession.ClearCache();
        webControl.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        webControl.Margin = new Thickness(0, -4, 0, 0);
        webControl.ShowContextMenu += webControl_ShowContextMenu;
        webControl.ConsoleMessage += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args.Message);
        webControl.Crashed += (sender, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args.Status);
        webControl.LoadingFrame += this.webControl_LoadingFrame;
        webControl.LoadingFrameComplete += this.webControl_LoadingFrameComplete;
        webControl.CertificateError += (sender, args) =>
            {
                args.Handled = EventHandling.Default;
                args.Ignore = true;
            };

        WebCore.ResourceInterceptor = new CustomResourceInterceptor
                                          {
                                              RequestEnabled = true, 
                                              Headers =
                                                  new Dictionary<string, string>
                                                     {
                                                          {
                                                              "theme", 
                                                              shellView
                                                              .SelectedItem
                                                              .StyleSheet
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                          };

        this.documentPanel = new DockPane { Header = "NHS Confidential: Personal data about a patient", Content = webControl };

        this.dockingManager.AddDocument(this.documentPanel);

        webControl.DocumentReady += WebViewOnDocumentReady;
```

When I run the application I am not getting the web application loading in the browser control, I have tried accessing the Uri above in Internet Explorer and Chrome and the application loads in both, I have also tried different Uri's in the browser control and they all work.

I am really struggling with this specific Uri, the only issue that I have seen is that when i loaded this Uri in Chrome I get prompt to accept the client certificate (a dialog comes up with the root certificate listed)

I would like a sanity check that the code below is correct and I have not done anything wrong, also would like to know what the issue is, the contents of the log file are

```
[0807/143423:INFO:(0)] WebCore is now online.
[0807/143423:INFO:(0)] Running Awesomium 1.7.5.0
[0807/143423:INFO:Awesomium.NET(0)] Registering Javascript Callbacks
```

Nothing else gets output to either the log or the Output window in VS.

**EDIT:** I have checked the values of the LoadingFrameEventArgs and see no issues there, there are no SSL errors, the LoadingFrame event is fired but nothing else, I am really stuck with this!!

Comment: How are you trying to place this information into the control from the ViewModel?  Convention? Can you give us alittle more with Xaml for the definition of how the control is placed (UserControl / Page) and also how your viewmodel is structured, if you can?

Comment: The `webControl` is added to a DockContainer, I discovered that the issue was to do with the Web Application' SSL configuration, the site was setup with a client certificate such that when navigating to the site in Chrome you are prompted to select a certificate, changing this setting in IIS resolved the problem and the site loaded

Comment: Hello sir, I'm new to visual studio and Awesomium, and I have no idea what you are talking about above, is there a simpler way?